# Remove every 3rd char in php

Tags: php

I am trying to return the given string with every third letter removed.

This is the code I have so far:-

```
function removeThirdLetter($sentence){
    $output = "";
    for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($sentence);$i++){
        if($i % 3 != 0){
            $output .= $sentence[$i];
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

When I try to use it like this:-

```
$str = "Frank Sinatra";
echo removeThirdLetter($str);
```

It returns:-

> rak intr

When it should return:-

> FrnkSiata

How can I correct my logic?

Comment: Know how you can tell if it is correct? Try it and see.

Comment: have you tested it, you know? does it work as expected? or not?

Comment: ` if($i % 3 != 0){
            $output .= $sentence[$i];
        }`

Comment: I am probably more so asking if I am doing it "right"?

Comment: probably should do `for ( $i = 3; $i < strlen($sentence); $i += 3)`

Comment: @bozdoz is right, why do additional steps??

Comment: @user3091406 a better approach would have been first to test the code, and if it behaves correctly then ask "how can I improve this code?" at http://codereview.stackexchange.com else ask "this code doesn't work. I expect A but i get B. Why?". If you do this, you'll get upvotes and answers. I promise.

Comment: Close voters, now that this question has been edited please vote to re-open.

Comment: @user3091406 You should [flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521265/remove-every-3rd-char-in-php#) this to be re-opened.

Comment: @vascowhite I'd delete this altogether and rewrite a new one. sadly, a -4 question with 3 answers already isn't going to get a lot of attention

Comment: @STTLCU, that won't help the OP, it will count towards a Question Ban and isn't the way the site is designed to work. I have the answer for him if it is reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out the semi-colon after initialising the `$output` variable.
Also seeing as you are appending to a string it's better to use `.=` rather then `$output[] =` otherwise it tries to return `$output` as an array.
Also the `$i % 3 == 0` was only appending where it is the 3rd character (starting with the first character) rather then where it is not the 3rd character which your output text suggested you want.

The below works as per your example:

```
<?php
function removeThirdLetter($sentence){
    $output = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($sentence); $i++){
        if($i % 3 != 2){
            $output .= $sentence[$i];
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$str = "Frank Sinatra";
echo removeThirdLetter($str); // should return "FrnkSiata"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect.

You can check this just run it

In your code you remove each first and second letters.

Also you should know  that 0 % 3 == 0

In this case you can change it to

```
if($i == 0 || $i % 3 != 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, but returning an array instead of a string ;-)

So change `return $output;` to `return implode('', $output);` and it should return a string.

EDIT:
Because the OP changed the code in his question my answer doesn't make sense anymore... Thanks any ways for the downvote, the person who did should first look at the edit-history of the question.

Comment: It's better to just append strings together in the first place rather then create an array and implode them afterwards. (I haven't downvoted)

Comment: I know, I was just fixing his code to work, instead of rewriting it ;-)